# Portable GCC on a USB

Tags: linux, gcc, usb, portability

Is it possible to build GCC to run off of a USB stick? I'm looking to run some HDD benchmarks such as bonnie++, which requires GCC, on a number of systems that don't have internet access or GCC. The OS is a stripped down version of Linux and the OS drive capacity is severely limited so installing anything directly onto it is not an option.

Here are the steps that I've taken so far. I have followed these instructions step by step:
http://www.wikihow.com/Manually-Build-GNU-Compiler-Collection-from-Scratch-on-Linux-Mint-Static-Edition
I have gotten everything to build properly and copied onto a USB stick. I connected the stick to the desired system, mounted it, and added the gcc directory to the path. But when I attempt to run something like `gcc -v` I get a `gcc command not found` error. Am I missing a step or is what I'm attempting to do not possible?

*update*

I was able to get Ubuntu 12.04 and bonnie++ onto a flash drive. I plugged it into the system I was wanting to test and booted into Ubuntu. From there I was able to run bonnie++: `bonnie++ -d /tmp/foo -r $(free -m | grep 'Mem:' | awk '{print $2}') -u root:root`but during the test I got the following error `Writing intelligently...Can't write block.: No space left on device`. Considering the system I'm testing has 12 1TB drives in raid 6 I believe that bonnie++ is performing the test on the files system of the USB stick and not the drives on the raid configuration. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could go about writing to the raid drives from a bootable USB?

Regarding @roy_longbottom's suggestion, I am still researching that as an option. I have also come across [stress linux](http://www.stresslinux.org) which is a minimal live distro which comes equipped with bonnie++ among a slew of other benchmarks and hardware stress testing utilities. For those with experience with it, would running bonnie++ from stresslinux hit me with the same problems?

Comment: check that your usb stick is not mounted in noexec mode. (check the output of `mount`)

Comment: running `mount` gives me the following output `/dev/sdd1 on /mnt/usb type vfat (rw)`.

Comment: You could consider installing any distro on the usb drive and then booting it or chrooting into it. This would let you easily install and run all the dev tools and benchmarks you want without touching the OS drive.

Comment: I was actually considering booting a distro from USB as a plan B. I'm not too familiar with chroot but will look into it.

Comment: Why do you want GCC to run off a USB stick in order to run disk benchmarks? What you need is the compiled program and you can produce this on any system with a compatible CPU (and OS). You can save this on a USB stick and, subject to setting permission, if Linux, then run it on a range of systems, possibly copying it to the drive to be tested.

Comment: I thought that with the way bonnie++ worked, implementing a series of C function calls to performs reads/writes, that I would need a C compiler as well. The systems that I will be testing do not have a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I had never heard of Bonnie++, but I downloaded the tar.gz file. The format was not recognised under my Linux Ubuntu, but I decompressed it via Windows. It comprised more than 40 items with no execution files.

Then I found that I could install bonnie++ execution files (and other items) using “sudo apt-get install bonnie++” under Ubuntu. It installed the files (god knows where) but I tried running it. The program started and indicated writing files, then a second lot which was taking too long, so I killed the program after five minutes. It seems that there are numerous run time commands that can be used, but I don’t have a week to spare to study them. IT seems that bonnie++ was first designed to test such as Sun database systems and my view is that it is too complex for stripped down versions of  Linux.

You might be interested in my DriveSpeed benchmark (free). There are 32 bit and 64 bit versions for Linux, one for Windows and cut down varieties for ARM CPUs via Linux and Android.  Read more on my site with download links in the following (no Ads):

```
 http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/linux_disk_usb_lan_benchmarks.htm 
 http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/Raspberry%20Pi%20Benchmarks.htm#anchor20
 http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20benchmarks.htm#anchor17
```

Example output log file Linux:

```
     Current Directory Path: 
     /media/f816ec76-8bf2-4dd3-9e98-62934909a779/roy/all64/drivespeed2
     Total MB   11263, Free MB    9513, Used MB    1750

     Linux Storage Speed Test 64-Bit Version 1.1, Tue Feb  1 14:20:39 2011

                    Copyright (C) Roy Longbottom 2011

         8 MB File         1          2          3          4          5
     Writing MB/sec       4.33      76.73      76.15      82.40     105.84
     Reading MB/sec      57.37      86.62      83.40      80.74      82.34

        16 MB File         1          2          3          4          5
     Writing MB/sec      73.94     108.16      72.53     116.19     116.12
     Reading MB/sec      70.39     103.31     120.31     121.53     121.48

        32 MB File         1          2          3          4          5
     Writing MB/sec     113.01      76.67      73.20     115.83     116.05
     Reading MB/sec     105.19     102.41     113.15     121.55     120.59

     ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     8 MB Cached File      1          2          3          4          5
     Writing MB/sec    1271.71    1503.73    1496.38    1493.27    1491.68
     Reading MB/sec    3406.70    4015.11    4079.82    4081.24    4080.77

     ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     Bus Speed Block KB     64        128        256        512       1024
     Reading MB/sec      84.93     102.31     112.31     121.03     116.41

     ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 KB Reads File MB >    2      4      8     16     32     64    128
     Random Read msecs    0.43   0.39   0.45   3.01   4.49   5.93   6.69

     ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     500 Files   Write             Read             Delete
     File KB     MB/sec  ms/File   MB/sec  ms/File  Seconds
           2       7.54     0.27     7.67     0.27    0.015
           4      17.19     0.24    22.27     0.18    0.018
           8      20.24     0.40    27.21     0.30    0.017
          16      33.27     0.49    47.16     0.35    0.019
          32      52.67     0.62    67.20     0.49    0.016
          64      55.43     1.18    75.49     0.87    0.015

                  End of test Tue Feb  1 14:21:29 2011
```

Comment: That looks great, thanks! I set up Ubuntu 12.04 on a 16gb usb flash drive and installed bonnie++ and build-essentials onto it over the weekend. I'll also look further into DriveSpeed benchmark and add that as well. The plan is to plug the drive into the desired system, chroot into it, and see how things go from there.